# Conflict in jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made two boxes with tabs.

But, the tabs of the boxes change in the same time =/

Demo:

http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/syxah/

Can anyone help-me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Still don't working =/ http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/syxah/?editors=101

Comment: i changed your 3 and 4 id's to xxx3/xxx4 - and it seems to work just fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ehAlJ

Comment: Could you please explain what the problem is exactly, I can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Your li's

```
<li data-id="#content-item-1">Capítulo 1</li>
<li data-id="#content-item-2" class="ajustment">Arquivos e Lições</li>
```

target these div's

```
<div id="content-item-1" class="inside">
<div id="content-item-2" class="inside content-2">
```

Your second set

```
<li data-id="#content-item-3" class="active">Capítulo 1</li>
<li data-id="#content-item-2" class="ajustment">Arquivos e Lições</li>
```

Your second set of div's have the same id - and your `li's` aren't targeting the correct div

```
<div id="content-item-1" class="inside">
<div id="content-item-2" class="inside content-2">
```

Change second set to this

```
<li data-id="#content-item-3" class="active">Capítulo 1</li>
<li data-id="#content-item-4" class="ajustment">Arquivos e Lições</li>
```

and divs

```
<div id="content-item-3" class="inside">
<div id="content-item-4" class="inside content-2">
```

[EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ehAlJ)

Comment: thanks for the reply! 


But the intention is that the tabs on the top box worked regardless of the bottom box

Comment: so you want the tabs on top to target the ones on bottom too?

Comment: I want to work independent forms